# Extracting data from a UCI dataset Online using python if the file is compressed(.zip)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, dataset

I want to use web scrapping to get the data from file
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00380/YouTube-Spam-Collection-v1.zip

How can I do that using **requests** in python?

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question with some more details, so that we can reproduce your issue. [ask] -> How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example how to load the zip file using `requests` and built-in [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) module:

```py
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile


url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00380/YouTube-Spam-Collection-v1.zip"

with ZipFile(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content), "r") as myzip:
    # print content of zip:
    # print(myzip.namelist())

    # print content of one of the file:
    with myzip.open("Youtube01-Psy.csv", "r") as f_in:
        print(f_in.read())
```

Prints:

```
b'COMMENT_ID,AUTHOR,DATE,CONTENT,CLASS\n

...
```